# What is the most influential article every programmer should read?

Tags: resources, article

I think some articles can change the world. What is your best article about programming?

Answer (score 2):

[How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

(and you better make this into a community wiki, or it will get closed faster than you can blink :p )

Answer (score 1):

The first one that comes to mind is Edsger Dijkstra's ["Goto statement considered harmful"](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF).